# Service broker error: Internal Server Error on binding service to an app

Tags: swisscomdev

I am working with the Application Cloud from Swisscom, based on Cloud Foundry. I have been trying unsuccessfully to bind an app with an amqp service.

When trying to bind it, I get

Unexpected Response
Response code: 502
CC code:       0
CC error code: 
Request ID: 9ed6d4a0-05f3-46bb-538d-a6073c887841::a9cc7039-23a8-4f56-8918-0214eea16ff3

```
Description:   {
  "description": "Service broker error: Internal Server Error",
  "error_code": "CF-ServiceBrokerBadResponse",
  "code": 10001,
  "http": {
    "uri": "http://open-service-broker.service.consul:8080/cf-broker/v2/service_instances/5d23994a-679f-4e8d-8334-67b3b895d3b7/service_bindings/13ae07b4-5dc6-4e58-bae6-e15cec1b2a3a",
    "method": "PUT",
    "status": 500
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per their status page, there's currently an outage affecting the rabbitmq service which will be the root cause of your issue:
https://status.developer.swisscom.com/